# Issue with JAVASCRIPT SDK for EVERNOTE

Tags: javascript, evernote

I am working on evernote javascript SDK [evernote@2.0.1-beta], things worked fine till I tried to make the following call ::

```
 noteStore.getNoteWithResultSpec(guid, {includeContent:true, includeResourcesData: true})
```

The call to this function `getNoteWithResultSpec`fails when my notes on evernote contain binary data e.g. [img / pdf] etc. However if my notes only contain text data [ no img / pdf ] then this function works fine.

The console shows the following ::

```
 evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/transport/memBuffer.js:32
    if (this.offset + len > this.buffer.length) throw Error('MemBuffer overrun');
                                                ^

Error: MemBuffer overrun
    at Error (native)
    at MemBuffer.read (/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/transport/memBuffer.js:32:55)
    at BinaryProtocol.readBinary (/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/protocol/binaryProto
col.js:327:29)
    at BinaryProtocol.readType (/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/protocol/binaryProtoco
l.js:355:25)
    at Object.Thrift.Struct.readFields (/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/thrift.js:505:
49)
    at Thrift.Struct.read (/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/thrift.js:485:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same issue but [this](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js/issues/65) looks similar. I would suggest that you create a new issue on Github so it'll be taken care of.